# redirect http://www.example.com/ to https://www.example.com/ with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using this as a solution.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

But I keep getting this error.
"Not all versions of your page point to the same URL."
Only the URL containing 'http://www.example.com/ does not redirect to the 'https' but rest all redirects properly.

Comment: did you change it in `config.php`?

Comment: Multiple RewriteCond get joined with an implicit AND (unless you specify otherwise, using the `OR` flag.) You are demanding that the HTTP_HOST is not empty AND does not start with `www.` AND the request is not HTTPS already. Requesting `http://www.example.com/` fails on the second one of these conditions.

Comment: "But I keep getting this error" – Where is this error reported? The browser? The server logs? Some third party tool?

Comment: I check my website rank on woorank which shows this error 'Not all versions of your page point to the same URL'

Comment: @hemant what changes do I need to make in config.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: tried this but now when I try to open my website it's not working... Is there something that I'm missing on?? or something that I also need to make a change somewhere else like for eg. in config.php or so because currently, I have set my base_url as 'https://www.example.com/' .. Please suggest if I'm missing on something..

Comment: You need to set three things. 1- htaccess RewriteBase 2- htaccess above https rule 3- base_url in application/config/config.php. Please share all code or screenshot

Comment: /---htaccess---/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

/---config---/
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.example.com/';

Comment: Please do email at `ping@naveedramzan.com`

Comment: Please check your email.